Can I mass insert one column of data from an Excel file to a table using existing data from the same table and using a select statement?
I am trying to insert new data into an table using existing data from the same table as reference.
For example:
Insert into dbo.table1
(column1,column2,column3,column5,column5,id)
select column1,column2,column3,column5,column5,id = '' --the id is being pulled from xlsx
from dbo.table1
where column1 = '12345'
and id = 'xyz' --copying from this id to the id value above`

So i can run this 1 at a time and it works just fine but I need to be able to do it 141 times w/o having to copy and paste 141 times. I am hoping that I can use a single script to insert 141 records using the same reference id.
Insert into dbo.table1
(column1,column2,column3,column5,column5,id)
select column1,column2,column3,column5,column5,id = 'abc'
from dbo.table1
where column1 = '12345'
and id = 'xyz' --copying from this id to the id value above
--(1 row affected)--

Insert into dbo.table1
(column1,column2,column3,column5,column5,id)
select column1,column2,column3,column5,column5,id = 'def'
from dbo.table1
where column1 = '12345'
and id = 'xyz' --copying from this id to the id value above
--(1 row affected)--

Insert into dbo.table1
(column1,column2,column3,column5,column5,id)
select column1,column2,column3,column5,column5,id = 'ghi'
from dbo.table1
where column1 = '12345'
and id = 'xyz' --copying from this id to the id value above
--(1 row affected)--


Please provide more info. What RDBS are you using? Is your SQL statement being run from the RDBMS interface, or from Excel VBA? If the former, you could just use Excel formulas to create multiple INSERT statements for your criteria then paste and run them all at once in the db interface. One statement per Excel row. Simple & reusable.

I think you are doing something wrong. Because copying the same rows into the same table violates first normal form. Or did I misunderstand something?
